# mouse wheel not working in v-dialog with css overflow set as overlay

Tags: css, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js, overflow

Reproduction Link: https://codepen.io/kingyue737/pen/BaVdjmg

This repro is modified from official example https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/dialogs/#scrollable

The only difference is that I add `overflow: overlay` to `v-card-text` in the dialog:

```html
<!-- line 22 in codepen -->
<v-card-text style="height: 300px; overflow-y: overlay">
```

Then I can no longer scroll by mouse wheel. I can't understand why. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: overflow: overlay is not well supported yet : https://caniuse.com/css-overflow-overlay.
Use overflow: auto; instead.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `overflow-y: overlay` from  `<v-card-text...`

**eg:**

```
<v-card-text style="height: 300px;">
```

Comment: I ask why adding `overflow-y: overlay` will prevent mouse wheel. Then you let me remove it...

Comment: did you try overflow-y: auto?